# why can I not connect to my hive DB?

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hive, hadoop2

I'm new to hive. I'm trying this code [enter link description here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveClient)

This my code

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class HiveJdbcClient {
    private static String driverName = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName(driverName);
            System.out.println("Drive loaded...");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.out.println("Before Connecting to hive...");
        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://servername:10001/test","hive","hive");
            System.out.println("Connected to hive..");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            String tableName = "testHiveDriverTable";
            ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("create table " + tableName + " (key int, value string)");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

    }
}
```

When I run program It's executed only driver loading step, but when DriverManager.getConnection() executed it runs forever. So it doesn't give any exception or error. So please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: probably blocking, waiting for a connection - try debugging

Comment: In debug modes also it runs forever

Comment: YEAH, but where does it block?

Comment: Blocking means it doesn't get connection.But Hive server is running.

Comment: so edit your question to be - why can I not connect to my hive DB?  Or rather search for an answer. Maybe firewall (client or host), maybe hive db settings?

Comment: Hi Scary, Program block in this line. Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://PDLFSHADOOP:10001/test","hive","hive");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66628/discussion-between-vijay-shinde-and-scary-wombat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer.
I Use hiveserver2.

This is my code that works.

```
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class HiveJdbcClient {
    private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
//  org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName(driverName);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.out.println("Before Connecting to hive...");
        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://<Server_name>:10001/test","hive_username","hive_password");
            System.out.println("Connected to hive..");

            // Select query
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            String sql = "select * from test.emp";
            System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
            ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while (res.next()) {
                System.out.println(String.valueOf(res.getInt(1)) + "\t" + res.getString(2));
            }

            // load data into table
            // NOTE: filepath has to be local to the hive server
            // NOTE: /tmp/a.txt is a ctrl-A separated file with two fields per line
            String tableName = "test.emp";
            String filepath = "D:\\datatoload\\emp1.txt";
            sql = "load data local inpath '" + filepath + "' into table " + tableName;
            System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
            boolean result = stmt.execute(sql);
            if(!result)
                System.out.println("Data load successfully!!!");
            else
                System.out.println("Failed to load data!!!");

            // regular hive query
            sql = "select count(*) from " + tableName;
            System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
            res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while (res.next()) {
                System.out.println(res.getString(1));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Below are the required jars.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

start hiveserver service on command line and then try, 
to run hive server 
**hive --service hiveserver &**